# stdlibc++ headers not found error on xcode 10

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++11, libc++

We have some c libraries written for our iOS project and after upgrading to Xcode 10, when compiling we get the error:

```
error: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass ‘-std=libc++’
on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
[-Werror,-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
        1 error generated.
```

Where do we need to make changes in out makefiles? Because I don't find the '-std='argument in them.

Answer (score -2):

Find the answer in Apple's developers forum.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106114
The sdk tools needs to be copied from older Xcode.

Comment: this is a hack not a solution. We added CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ our external library Makefile and removed -stdlib=stdlibc++